# Jackson: @JsonTypeInfo missing in Arrays

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I found some strange behavior of the Jackson JSON Processor library and i am curious whether this is intentional or a bug. Please have a look at the code below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NAME)
public class Nut {}
```

…

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Nut nut = new Nut();
Object object = new Nut();
Nut[] nuts = new Nut[] { new Nut() };
Object[] objects = new Object[] { new Nut() };

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(nut));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(object));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(nuts));
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(objects));
```

Output:

```
{"@type":"Nut"}
{"@type":"Nut"}
[{"@type":"Nut"}]
[{}]
```

What i expect (and want) is the following:

```
{"@type":"Nut"}
{"@type":"Nut"}
[{"@type":"Nut"}]
[{"@type":"Nut"}] // <<< type information included
```

Do i miss something or should i file a bug report?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior.  When traversing an object graph for serialization, Jackson uses the *declared* type of an object when determining what type information to include.  The elements in `objects` have declared type Object, which you haven't told Jackson to include any type information for.

Jackson only looks at the runtime type of the top-level argument to `writeValueAsString`, because the method argument has type `Object`; it's not possible in Java to know the declared type of an object passed as an argument to a method (even with generics, thanks to type erasure), so your first two examples (`writeValueAsString(nut)` and `writeValueAsString(object)` are effectively identical).

More information here: http://jackson-users.ning.com/forum/topics/mapper-not-include-type-information-when-serializing-object-why

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation, especially for pointing out that the first two examples are identical in their behavior since i was not quite aware of that yet. Is there a possibility to force the usage of actual types inside of containers? Annotating the Object class (through mix-in) does not fit my needs (maybe i should open a follow-up question to present the context of my actual problem).

Comment: In the discussion I linked, Tatu says, "[Jackson] MUST use declared type, to ensure that same type information settings are used; otherwise information could depend on per-element basis, and this distinction is impossible to figure out during deserialization", so I think your only options are to enable type information for Object (or enableDefaultTyping on the ObjectMapper), or change the type of your array.  If you open a follow-up question, be sure to explain your use case and why you can't do either of those.

Comment: You may want to enable so-called "Default Typing", which can be used to include type information for `java.lang.Object` entries (or other groups of classes you can't or don't want to annotate).

Comment: I tried both suggestion before (and now again to be sure) and could not make it work - i opened a follow-up question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14631502/2021412. Thank you anyways for your efforts.