# jsonrpc4j: How to add type info to parameters?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, deserialization

I am using [jsonrpc4j](http://code.google.com/p/jsonrpc4j/) and got stuck. I made a little example to show my problem:

Abstract class:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
@JsonSubTypes(value = { @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Walnut.class) })
public abstract class Nut {

}
```

Concrete subclass:

```
public class Walnut extends Nut {

}
```

Interface for the service:

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
    public Nut getNut();
    public void setNut(Nut nut);
}
```

The service itself:

```
public class Service implements ServiceInterface {
    public Nut getNut() { return new Walnut(); }
    public void setNut(Nut nut) {}
}
```

Server:

```
JsonRpcServer rpcServer = new JsonRpcServer(new ObjectMapper(), new Service());
StreamServer streamServer = new StreamServer(rpcServer, 50, 1420,
        50, InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"));
streamServer.start();
```

Client:

```
JsonRpcClient jsonRpcClient = new JsonRpcClient(new ObjectMapper());
ServiceInterface remoteService = ProxyUtil.createClientProxy(
        ServiceInterface.class.getClassLoader(),
        ServiceInterface.class, jsonRpcClient,
        new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 1420));
```

If i call *remoteService.getNut()* everything works as expected, the log prints:

```
JSON-PRC Request: {"id":"6064348714687420633","jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"getNut"}
JSON-PRC Response: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":"6064348714687420633",
        "result":{"@type":"Walnut"}}
```

If i call *remoteService.setNut(new Walnut())* the server throws an exception, the log prints:

```
JSON-PRC Request {"id":"9194853851254039397","jsonrpc":"2.0",
        "method":"setNut","params":[{}]}
Error in JSON-RPC Service com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
        Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME:
        missing property '@type' that is to contain type id  (for class Nut)
```

The type information of the parameter is missing because the proxy wraps all parameters into one object array (see my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14582343/2021412) to understand why the info type is missing in this case).

How can i achieve the desired serialization? I tried to enable default typing and to annotate (with @JsonTypeInfo) the *Object.class* via mix-in, but both failed (exceptions below).

With enabled default typing [*remoteService.getNut()*, error on server side]:

```
Exception while handling request
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
        Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY:
        need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for
        class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
```

With enabled default typing [*remoteService.setNut(new Walnut())*, error on client side]:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        Unexpected token (START_ARRAY), expected VALUE_STRING:
        need JSON String that contains type id (for subtype of
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)
```

With mix-in [*remoteService.getNut()*, error on server side]:

```
Exception while handling request
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        Could not resolve type id 'DefaultErrorResolver$ErrorData'
        into a subtype of
        [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode]
```

With mix-in [*remoteService.setNut(new Walnut())*, error on client side]:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
        [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
        com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be better if you post ONLY the relevant portion of code, it's too lengthy to read..!

Comment: This is a minimum working example and I can not think of one line to omit in this case - if you could point out any irrelevant portions i am maybe able to improve my question.

Comment: I think having the complete code is a great benefit. I frequently see requests for more code from followup questions on SO and many forums and my own handling of support requests has frequently followed this pattern. It's fairly compact, it only includes the classes necessary to make the question stand on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my issue by patching the library. Now it serializes all parameters one by one and concatenate them afterwards. Bug report and patch can be found at http://code.google.com/p/jsonrpc4j/issues/detail?id=49.